# Countdown PHP Working on Localhost but not on my server

Tags: php, html, countdown

I'm using [this tutorial](https://litmus.com/community/learning/27-how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-your-email) to create a countdown clock for an email, but for some reason the PHP code [works fine on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XWT8.png) but doesn't work at all when I upload it to my server. You can see the HTML code I'm using here on my staging website (http://2loot.com/staging/countdownemail/).

I've double checked all of the urls to make sure I'm linking to the correct files. I've checked the console and can't see any errors, but I'm quite new to PHP, so I'm wondering if there is something dumb I'm doing, or if there is a server-side restriction. Also, when I try to post this via mailchimp, I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

The gif.php code is:

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    include 'GIFEncoder.class.php';
    include 'php52-fix.php';

    $time = isset($_GET['time']) ? $_GET['time'] : 0;

    $future_date = new DateTime(date('r',strtotime($time)));
    $time_now = time();
    $now = new DateTime(date('r', $time_now));
    $frames = array();  
    $delays = array();


    $image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');

    $delay = 100;

    $font = array(
        'size' => 64,
        'angle' => 0,
        'x-offset' => 97,
        'y-offset' => 255,
        'file' => 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
        'color' => imagecolorallocate($image, 69, 37, 60),
    );
    for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++){

        $interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);

        if($future_date < $now){
            // Open the first source image and add the text.
            $image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');
            $text = $interval->format('00  00  00  00');
            imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
            ob_start();
            imagegif($image);
            $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
            $delays[]=$delay;
            $loops = 1;
            ob_end_clean();
            break;
        } else {
            // Open the first source image and add the text.
            $image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');
            $text = $interval->format('0%a  %H  %I  %S');
            imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
            ob_start();
            imagegif($image);
            $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
            $delays[]=$delay;
            $loops = 0;
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        $now->modify('+1 second');
    }

    //expire this image instantly
    header( 'Expires: Mon, 8 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT' );
    header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
    header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
    $gif = new AnimatedGif($frames,$delays,$loops);
    $gif->display();
```